# Insert image links corresponding to the right product id on MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I want some help, and I hope you could help me on this.
I'm working in a gallery script, where users create a certain product
and the upload product's images. Now the MySQL part. Here's how I proceed.

-1: Add a new product on the products table: (productid, userid, productname)

```
$insertproduct="insert into products(userid, productname) values
   ('3', 'Leather Jacker')";
   db->query($insertproduct);
```

Then I get the productid in this way:

```
$getproductid = $db->query("SELECT max(productid) from products where userid=3");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($getproductid))
  {
   $pid=$row[0];
  }
```

To later use productid when inserting imagelinks corresponding to that product

```
$query = "insert into images(imagelink, productid) values
                    ('".$imagelink."', '".$pid."')";                      
$insert = $db->query($query);
```

BUT when I check the database everything's fine except for 'productid=0'
so its like:

imgid   imagelink                  productid

166 203572012_1547_17_1.jpg    0

And when I replace $pid with some static number, productid seems to get saved correctly

imgid   imagelink                  productid
166 203572012_1547_17_1.jpg    541

So I'm thinking maybe the problem is here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($getproductid))
  {
   $pid=$row[0];
  }
```

Help me please. This problem is driving me crazy.
PS: I'm a beginner so please dont judge me :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($getproductid)` with `$row = $getproductid->fetch_row()` and i think this too `db->query($insertproduct);` with `$db->query($insertproduct);`

Comment: Hello rohit, Thank you for your help I already have the second one:
$db->query($insertproduct); I dont know why the $ sign disappeared
maybe while I was editing the code here. Anyways I did what you told
me to and it works now. Thank you. Interesting is the fact that 

$pid=$row[0];
('".$imagelink."', '".$pid."')";

if I remove $pid and leave it only $row[0], when i enter it on:

('".$imagelink."', '".$row[0]."')";

It doest work.


THANK YOU VERY MUCH :):):)

Comment: glad to help you. Please give a green Tick if you are satiesfied ;-)